# What kind of power supply do I need for Lenovo H320

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

What kind of power supply do I need for a [Lenovo H320](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883108363&Tpk=lenovo%20h320) to run a low profile graphics card [like this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130594) that requires 300 watts, given how small the case is?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a PSU of 500 Watts, but Lenovo  does not have this type of PSU for your computer case. FSP Inc. did special PSU for Lenovo.

This PC has an Expansion PCI Expressx16 slot for video card and you cannot install any video card you like because the power supply is only 180 Watts and it's not compatible with any other PSU from the manufacturer.